# How to search and replace words with common suffix in vim gvim?

Tags: awk, vim, sed

Eg.

```
abc_def_ghi_xyz
uvw_mno_gab_xyz
bac_cab_lmn_xyz
```

should be replaced with

```
ABC_xyz
ABC_xyz
ABC_xyz
```

How to do using `awk`, `%s` and `sed` commands ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question(which you have put in order to solve your own problem); which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F_ '{print "ABC_"$NF}' file
```

Where:

```
 -F_  .............. _ as field separator
 "ABC_" ............ literal ABC_
 $NF ............... last field
```

Using vim:

```
:%s/.*\ze_xyz/ABC
```

Using sed:

```
sed -r 's/.*(_xyz)/ABC\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using %s:

```
 :%s/*_xyz/ABC_xyz/g
```

I would also suggest looking at :h about vim search and replace.